# What spec/version of Websockets does iOS 5.1+ use?

Tags: ios5, websocket

I've been making adjustments to a websocket server I'm using, but I'm finding my efforts in vain since I haven't been able to determine which spec (hixie/hybi?) of websockets the most recent version of iOS is using.

Is it Hixie 76 or Hybi? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about iOS 5.1, but prior to that it was Hixie. Can you dump the initial header request sent by the client? I can identify the spec from the initial connection request.

Comment: I'll see if I can dump it...I'll might need to re-write some of the server code (working on webbit) so might take a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is test link, use any device / platform to test it: http://websocketstest.com/

On iPhone 4 (Version 5.0.1) supports [drawft-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76).

And here is overall support statistics of availability of technology over different browsers / platforms: http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: Perfect thanks, i'll definitely use it to test out future stuff ;)